# Leading commas in python/pandas read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file I wish to load into pandas, but the formatting is giving me some problems. The file is such:

> Version 1
>
> ,Date Time,Name,Value
>
> ,26/Jan/2016 07:35:52,Name1,340rqi
>
> ,26/Jan/2016 07:00:00,Name2,1.00E+005
>
> ,26/Jan/2016 07:00:00,Name3,pulled_9

(It's a mess of a file, but the main point is that there is an empty 1st column and an empty 1st row with just 'Version 1' in position 0,0)

I am using the following code to get it into my DF:

```
filename_cv = '123456789.csv'
sheet_cv = filename_cv[:-4] #trimming off the .csv part
df_cv = pandas.read_csv(filename_cv, sheet_cv,engine='python')
```

But the output is not desirable. This is what I get:

> df_cv
>
> Out[4]:
>
> Version 1
>
> 0 ,26/Jan/2016 07:35:52,Name1,340rqi
>
> 1 ,26/Jan/2016 07:00:00,Name2,1.00E+005
>
> 2 ,26/Jan/2016 07:00:00,Name3,pulled_9

I think those leading commas are my problem, but is there a good way to get rid of them?

I know I can trim rows and change the index (skiprows), but those leading commas are the source of my issue I am sure.

I want the comma separate values to go into their own columns like normal.

What's wrong?

Comment: use `skiprows=1` parameter in the `read_csv()` function

Comment: This is true, but the column's leading commas don't go away. This will still cause the whole row to be formatted as a string instead of individual CSV values.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
In [313]: df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv', skiprows=1)

In [314]: df
Out[314]:
   Unnamed: 0             Date Time   Name      Value
0         NaN  26/Jan/2016 07:35:52  Name1     340rqi
1         NaN  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name2  1.00E+005
2         NaN  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name3   pulled_9

In [315]: df = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)

In [316]: df
Out[316]:
              Date Time   Name      Value
0  26/Jan/2016 07:35:52  Name1     340rqi
1  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name2  1.00E+005
2  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name3   pulled_9
```

if youwant to parse your date-time column, use this:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), skiprows=1, parse_dates=['Date Time'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:

This can be fixed by not specifying the sheet name in the read_csv() command. Obvious 'duh' since the csv file does not have multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Supplying an alternative argument for the delimiter makes the ',' explicit.

```
import pandas as pd

filename_cv = '123456789.csv'
sheet_cv = filename_cv[:-4] #trimming off the .csv part
df = pd.read_csv(filename_cv, sheet_cv, engine='python',  skiprows=1, delimiter=',')
df = df.filter(regex='^((?!Unnamed).)*$')
print df
```

.

```
              Date Time   Name      Value
0  26/Jan/2016 07:35:52  Name1     340rqi
1  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name2  1.00E+005
2  26/Jan/2016 07:00:00  Name3   pulled_9
```